# Where to Store Purchased Content and Exported Data

Tags: ios, storage

The app I'm working on generally uses a single SQL store in Core Data to hold a working dataset for the app.  However, there can be any number of small, separate stores which originated as either

- In-app Purchased content, or
- Exported subsets of the working dataset that may be reused from time to time.

These will always consist of a single sqlite file (WAL turned off).  The In-App purchases can always be re-downloaded, but it would be possible for the exported data to be lost for good (since they might choose to permanently delete the data after it is exported).

Intuitively, since the exported data might not be possible to recreate, it should go in a subdirectory of the documents folder.  But I'm not sure whether Apple would agree about that.

I have no idea where the downloaded purchased content should be saved, since technically, it can be re-downloaded at any time.

So, my question is, where in the iOS filesystem should I put these (iOS7 and beyond).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official, public guidance on where content purchased via IAP should go on the filesystem. However, experience with Data Storage Guidelines feedback has indicated that:

- `NSDocumentsDirectory` should only contain data created or edited by the user
- (some) Non-user data can still be stored in `NSDocumentsDirectory` if it has the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute set. In general you should still try and avoid doing this.
- In-App Purchase content is considered "restorable application data" and should be stored accordingly. The application support directory is one place where it could be stored.

If your exported data was exported by a user-initiated action and the data at that point "belongs" to the user, storing that exported data in the `NSDocumentsDirectory` should be fine. If you have any doubt, store it in the application support directory or caches directory. Be aware that in low space conditions the data may be purged by the system.